# Using Google Sheets with Android Application

Tags: android, google-api, google-sheets, google-drive-android-api

I want to Create and Insert data into user's private Google Sheet Created by him/her from an android application.Is there any way to get permission after OAUTH, either from sheets api or Google Drive api to do this? if so, then how?

Comment: If you want to access non-public user data then your application must be authorized by the user. This is done through Oauth 2.0 flow from Sheets API. check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize for more information. Your application should have https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds scope.